# Extract part of the URL path and insert it via variable in Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, extract

Any idea how could I extract part of the URL path. For example, I want to extract just a part of the URL, which is different on all URLs
site.com/product/9530/product-name.html
Here I need only the number "9530"
Also I need to create a variable in Google Tag Manager that captures that number from all URLs of my site!
Hope that I have explained my case :)

Comment: You could probably write a custom JS variable that does that for you. Pretty standard string parsing techniques would apply. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should at least try to google this basic stuff..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which part of the URL this number is placed on different site pages.

If this number is always placed after "/product" you can create custom javascript variable like:

```
function () {
var urlPart = document.location.pathname.split('product/')[1].split('/')[0];
return urlPart; }
```

If this number can occur in other places of the URL please specify in what places this could be met and whether there are other numbers in the URL.

Comment: Yes, the number is always after /product/

Comment: Nice. Then try to create variable with this code snippet and test it. Should work:)

Comment: While this covers your needs for extra "cool" points you could use the new regex table variable with the page path as input variable and a regex with a capture group to extract the number.