# Extract from a page path or url excluding a specific format

Tags: extract, google-tag-manager

I am currently working on a Google Tag Manager regex formula but what it needs to do is just show a specific word/s from a page path or page url.

For example:
/page/course/tag-manager-lesson1/?
/page/course/tag-manager-topic1/?

1st Output is "tag-manager" then
2nd Output is either "lesson1" or "topic1"

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819245/extract-part-of-the-url-path-and-insert-it-via-variable-in-tag-manager) closely similar but somehow a little different on what is being extracted.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript Variable

```js
function(){
  var allMatches = Array.from("/page/course/tag-manager- 
  lesson1/?".matchAll(/.*(tag-manager)-(\w+)\//g))
  var result = [allMatches[0][1], allMatches[0][2]]
  return result;
}
```

This should work. Or you have other more complicated page path than this.